# How to Move Bottom Unity Launcher in Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

I want move unity launcher to bottom. I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paullo612/unityshell-rotated 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install unityshell-rotated libnux-1.0-0 compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Console say "unityshell-rotated" and "libnux-1.0-0" packate not found. 
What should i do ?

EDIT: 
I want be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qDds.png

Comment: Any future updates to this duplicate question should/will be found in the link now in your question.  Currently you cannot do this.  The PPA you have linked to is for 11.10 only.

Comment: You could use another dock, such as Cairo-dock or Plank.

Comment: @fossfreedom When it comes on 14.04. Do you know this ?

Comment: @user292299 - never say never - but read the answers on the duplicate.  Highly unlikely that moving the launcher will be made officially by devs.  A solution will likely only be offered by a third-party who is willing to get their development-hands dirty.